# Launch Type vs. Capacity Provider Strategy for Fargate Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a Fargate service running using [NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs-patterns.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService.html) from the CDK, and am currently trying to configure autoscaling for the service. When looking at my service through the ECS console, I see that the tasks running under it have "Fargate" as the launch type. Since it uses launch type, there's no way to specify a capacity provider strategy (from note in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html)). I've read a bit about capacity providers, and I'm not sure I actually need to worry about them. As far as I can tell, you can define a capacity provider strategy to specify a split between different capacity providers. For Fargate, the capacity provider choices are FARGATE and FARGATE_SPOT. For my service, I would want only FARGATE providers. Is there a difference between using the Fargate launch type and using a capacity provider strategy that's 100% FARGATE? Is there even a way to specify a capacity provider strategy for your tasks through the CDK?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Corresponded with someone from AWS who confirmed that there is no difference between launching a service using the Fargate launch type vs. using 100% FARGATE type capacity providers. Thus, it isn't necessary to add capacity providers to your cluster if you don't plan on using FARGATE_SPOT. Simply using the Fargate launch type is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

With the AWS Fargate Capacity provider, you'll be able to use Fargate SPOT.

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-fargate-spot-now-generally-available/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deep-dive-into-fargate-spot-to-run-your-ecs-tasks-for-up-to-70-less/

This is the main difference between launch a task/service task with and without it.

Comment: Please note that links are only considered additional info. The answer to the question is expected to still become clear if the links are ignored. When ignoring the links I do not really see how this answers the question. Please [edit] to make the answer in the non-link part more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there even a way to specify a capacity provider strategy for your tasks through the CDK?

Support for capacity providers in CloudFormation (CDK maps to CloudFormation) is **incomplete**:

- [Full support for Capacity Providers in CloudFormation.](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/631)

For example, when creating an ECS service, you **can't explicitly set** preferred capacity provider as you can do using CLI's [create-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html) or [run-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).
Thus you can't specify capacity provider for at service or run-task level.

Comment: I see. That's too bad. I think I'll stick to the Fargate launch type, then.